# Attack on ElGamal Encryption

Tags: elgamal-encryption

Bob is holding a secret-bid auction using ElGamal encryption. He chooses a “safe” prime $p$ of sufficient size, a generator $g$ in $\operatorname{QR}(\mathbb Z_p)$ and a value $b$ in $[1, p]$. He then calculates the value $B = g^b\bmod p$, and publishes the values $g$ and $B$.

Alice wants to place a bid with value $m$. She chooses a random value $k$ in $[1, p]$, and computes two values: $r = g^k \bmod p$, and $t = m\cdot B^k \bmod p$. The values Alice sends are $r$ and $t$.

Bob can recover Alice’s bid by calculating $m' = t \cdot r^{-b} \bmod p$.

Mallory intercepts Alice’s message, and can replace it with her own. She wants to inflate Alice’s bid by 10x to make sure Alice pays a much higher price than necessary. What value does Mallory change Alice’s bid to? Let the new values be $r'$ and $t'$.

How do you approach this problem?

Comment: Put yourself in the state of mind of Mallory. What's your goal ? Express that as an equation in term of $m$ and $m'$ (for the later, as Bob computes it). Translate that into an equation in term of other variables, including $r$ and $t$ that Mallory gets (form Alice), $B$ (which is public), $b$ (known only to Bob), and $r'$ and $t'$ that Mallory chooses (and intoxicates Bob with). Then find how Mallory chooses $r'$ and $t'$. Hint: if something is mysterious, don't mess with it.

Comment: To b sure, is $m$ the actual value of the bid? We expect it to be much smaller than $p$, or $(p-1)/2$ since it is a subgroup pf quadratic residues and $p$ is safe, right?